# Filter Record Types from Custom Button (URL)

Tags: custom-button, custom-url

I am trying to create a new Opportunity from an existing Case using a custom button.  I am able to pass in various parameters but I would like to also filter the Record Types on the initial selection screen.  Is this possible by adding extra parameters to the URL?

Comment: You can of course assign a specific record type with an URL parameter, but if you want to give the user a choice of record types, then a custom VF page plus controller is the only way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @sfdcfox.  VF is the way to go if you need to filter record Type options, no way to use page params in the native UI.

This is just a very simple example I drew up that could be used as a start .

**In VF Page**

```
<apex:form>

    <apex:selectList value="{!recTypeID}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!myOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
    </apex:selectList>

    <apex:commandButton value="Next" Action="{!continue}"/>

</apex:form>
```

**In controller**

```
    public class myController {

        private List<SelectOption> opts             {get;set;}
        private String oType                        {get;set;}
        public Id recTypeId                         {get;set;}

        myController(){
            //You could use something like this to make the page more dynamic if you pass in the sObjectType through a URL param
            //oType = system.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('oType');

            //Assuming you know the sObjectType, you can just set it here
            oType = 'Account';
        }

        public List<SelectOption> getMyOptions() {
            opts = new List<SelectOption>();

            opts.add(new SelectOption('','--Please Select Record Type --'));

            list<RecordType> rts = [Select Id, Name From RecordType Where sObjectType =: oType]

            /*
                Perform some logic here to filter out the record types you dont want as an option from your list
            */

            //For all remaining recordTypes in the list, add them as select options
            for(RecordType r : rts){
                opts.add(new SelectOption(r.id,r.name));
            }
            return opts;
        }

        public PageReference continue(){

            //If you used a page param to determine the object type, you will have to query for the sObject here, but this is assuming you know the sObject type
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();

            PageReference p = new PageReference('/' + res.getKeyPrefix() + '/e?RecordType=' + recTypeId);
            p.setRedirect(true);
            return p;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The user will automatically be given a choice of any record type available on their profile. You may want to consider a custom record type selection page (Visualforce) if you want to provide additional capability.